# filter a datagridview in Form 2 and return filtered data to datagridview in Form1

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

Please I really need help on this one... I have 2 Forms `Form1` and `Form2`. In `Form2` I Filter the `DGV` by `Textboxchanged event`

**TBC Code**

```
Dim dvSection As DataView
    Dim tableAdapter As New testDataSetTableAdapters.testingTableAdapter
    Dim ds As New testDataSet
    dv.Table = TestDataSet.testing
    dv.RowFilter = "CONVERT(TransactionID, System.String) LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"
    TestingDataGridView.DataSource = dv
```

I return the filtered data by assigning the `dv` as the new `DataSource` for `Form1 DGV`.

**This Code Works**

```
    Form1.TestingDataGridView1.DataSource = dv
```

Here in my question, in `Form1` (with filtered data). I want to `Edit` the `data` in the `DGV` and then `Update` my `MySql Table "testing"`. I am really confused about this cause I've never done this before. I usually `Update` my `DGV` and `MySql Table` by using the ff codes. How ever in this situation the ff codes doesn't work.

```
 If MsgBox("Save Changes Made in this Cell?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation) = DialogResult.Yes Then
        Me.Validate()
        Me.TestingBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TestingTableAdapter.Update(Me.TestDataSet.testing)

    End If
```

I am really confused now, A little help would be really nice. Please and Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm finally able to update the data view now... Let me post my codes here for future reference just in case someone also needs help. this is a sample project so I didn't go much into the codes and went directly to how I solved it.

`Form1` has `Datagridview(databound), 1 button "Form2"`

**Codes for Form 1**

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        `TODO: This line of code loads data into the TestDataSet.testing table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.`

        Me.TestingTableAdapter.Fill(Me.TestDataSet.testing)

    End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Form2.Show()
        ' Me.Hide()'
        Me.TestingBindingSource.DataSource = TestDataSet
        Me.TestingTableAdapter.Dispose()
        Me.TestingTableAdapter.Fill(Me.TestDataSet.testing)

    End Sub

    Private Sub TestingDataGridView1_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles TestingDataGridView1.CellEndEdit

        If MsgBox("Save Changes Made in this Cell?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation) = DialogResult.Yes Then
            Me.Validate()
            Form2.TestingBindingSource().EndEdit()
            Me.TestingTableAdapter.Update(Me.TestDataSet.testing)

        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

`Form2` has `DGV (databound), 2Buttons, "Return",  "Save", and a textbox`

```
 Private Sub TestingBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TestingBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
        Me.Validate()
        Me.TestingBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.TestDataSet)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the TestDataSet.testing table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.'
        Me.TestingTableAdapter.Fill(Me.TestDataSet.testing)

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

        Dim tableAdapter As New testDataSetTableAdapters.testingTableAdapter
        Dim ds As New testDataSet

        dv.Table = TestDataSet.testing
        dv.RowFilter = "CONVERT(TransactionID, System.String) LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"
        TestingDataGridView.DataSource = dv
        Form1.TestingDataGridView1.DataSource = dv

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Form1.Show()
        Me.Hide()

        Me.TestingTableAdapter.Dispose()
        Me.TestingTableAdapter.Fill(Me.TestDataSet.testing)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If MsgBox("Save Changes Made in this Cell?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation) = DialogResult.Yes Then
            Me.Validate()
            Me.TestingBindingSource.EndEdit()
            Me.TestingTableAdapter.Update(Me.TestDataSet.testing)

        End If
    End Sub
```